# jMeter Beanshell get value from response with condition and put in variable

Tags: scripting, jmeter, beanshell

I have response from HTTP request:

```
{"d":
[
    ["","ACCOUNT INFO - 275000061036542815","","","","","","275000061036542815","978","002"],
    ["","275001122947712616","","","","","","275001122947712616","941","002"]
]
}
```

It has 2 sub arrays which shows all user accounts, and for some users, it could be more than two.
I need to extract value from the 7th index and put it in a variable, but only if the last one (like in example) is equal to "002". So, i need for loop which will check this, and it can stop when it finds the first useful result.
Maybe this can be done with regular expression extractor, I'm nost sure.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [regular expression extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of your request with the below configurations:

- **Field to check:** `Body`
- **Reference Name:** `MyVar` // or any name you want for the variable which will hold the value
- **Regular Expression:** `","(\d+).+"002"`
- **Template:** `$1$`
- **Match No:** `1`  // or you can use `-1` to get all the values.

You can add a [debug sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and a [view result tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) to check if your variable is holding the correct value.